# Access denied to default session when i try to send mail automatically using scheduler

Tags: java, session, jakarta-mail

I have a requirement of sending the Email automatically from and to my corporate Email account in specific Intervals of time. But I get `Access Denied to default session` Exception even though I am not using default instance. Authentication is not required. Please help me solve this exception and send mail in regular intervals

**MailServer.java**

```
public class MailServer extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{
        private String mailhost  ="host";  //"smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; //"smtp.mail.com";
    final String username = "username";
final String password = "password";
   private Session session;  

   public MailServer(String user, String password) {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "host");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, username);
        }
      });

    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
}  

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
    return new PasswordAuthentication(password, password);
}  

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception
{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));

        else

        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

        Transport.send(message);
}
```

**.properties File**

```
setFrom = fgf.er@xxx.com
setPassword=xxx


#repeat for every 10 seconds
timetoquery = 10s

  #start after 2seconds for first time..
  delay = 2s

  emailTO = fgh.gm@xxx.com,fgh.hg@xxx.com
```

**Testing.java**

```
public class Testing extends TimerTask
 {

   public void run()
   {

               MailServer sender = new MailServer(Constants.setFrom, Constants.setPassword);

               try {
              sender.sendMail("Subject","This is Java4s",Constants.setFrom,Constants.emailTO);
        }
               catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }  

            System.out.println("Email Sent Succesfully...");

        }
}
```

**CONSOLE**

```
Scheduler started..
java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied
at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:292)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:141)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
at java4s.MailServer.sendMail(MailServer.java:63)
at java4s.Testing.run(Testing.java:15)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Email Sent Succesfully...
```

Comment: I think it's a **typo** , In testing class you are creating Object of **GMailServer class** where as You posted code of **MailServer class**

Comment: It is a typo here. In my IDE I have given the correct class name.

Comment: if you are using gmail then prop are wrong

Comment: No I am using Outlook server with port 25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are shadowing a variable:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, username);
    }
  });

session = Session.getInstance(props, this); // this is the local variable not the instance one
```

so when in `sendMail`:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

session is `null` and java-mail tries to use the default one.

Comment: The Email is sent the specified Email ID. Now the problem is the From Email ID is not shown in both the new email alert and in the Inbox. From Mail ID is blank in the Inbox list but shown when the mail is opened

Comment: Sounds like a brand new question to me, feel free to post another question for the new issue.